# Activated VENV still use system pip and system python? What's wrong?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

When I activate a `venv`, `which pip` returns `/usr/local/bin/pip` instead of `path/to/my/apps/venv/bin/pop`. Why is that?

I am inclined to just `rm- rf` the pip in `/usr/local/bin/pip` and install again, but since this is a production server I prefer not to guess too much :-)

My concern is that I have (in usr/local/bin):

- easy_install
- easy_install-2.6
- pip
- pip-2.6
- virtualenv
- virtualenv-2.6

`python --version` returns 2.6.6 and `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python` even though `venv`is activated?

Running Debian Squeeze

Answer (score 1):

Check your virtualenv for a `local` directory. If `venv/local` exists, does it contain `pip` and `easy_install`? If it does, you can try working around this problem by editing `venv/bin/activate` and prepending `venv/local/bin` to your path just like `venv/bin` is being prepended.

Something like:

```
_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/local/bin:$PATH"  # my new line
export PATH
```

I'm having a problem similar to what I've described, and unfortunately I have not run it to ground yet. See also: [Why do distribute and pip install to my virtualenv's ./local/bin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370872/why-do-distribute-and-pip-install-to-my-virtualenvs-local-bin)

Answer (score 0):

What shell are you using?  What specific command did you use to activate the virtualenv?

In my case (also using squeeze) I am using bash and it if I run "source bin/activate" then everything in my path (pip, python, etc) is correct.

Comment: on my local machine I am using zsh - but on the debian box I use bash. I activate it like you do. -- HOWEVER: I remember I couldn't get colours to work, a loooooong time ago. That was fixed with this in `bash_profile`:

`if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then$                                                                                                                                                         
        source ~/.bashrc$
    fi
`
But that shouldn't matter.